# Mac executable with GCC 4.8 without MacPorts dependency

Tags: macos, gcc, ld, libgcc

```
gcc-mp-4.8 test.c
otool -L a.out
```

shows that the executable is linked with `/opt/local/lib/gcc48/libgcc_s.1.dylib`, and that's not what I want, because the path won't exist on a stock Mac OS X system.

How can I use MacPorts-installed GCC 4.8 to build MacPorts-independent executables that would use `/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib` instead?

I've tried adding `-L/usr/lib/ -lgcc_s.1` to arguments, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: So you modified a Makefile and it didn't do what you wanted, or you have a build script that doesn't send the correct arguments into the link stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc isn't meant to link against the library from older versions.. You should be able to statically link instead, however.